# Subreport visibility based on record count>0

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an Access 365 report that contains 3 subreports. I would like to make one of the subreports visible, only if it contains data.

My plan was to use a control that contains a count of records in this subreport. If that count is zero, then set visibility of the subreport to false.

The subreport is called "NegConsentOutputAccounts_subreport"
The control with the record count is "text45" in the main report (placeholder while I work this out)

I thought I could get away with something as simple as:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Text45 = 0 Then
        Me.NegConsentOutputAnnuity_subreport.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.NegConsentOutputAnnuity_subreport.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But apparently not. Triggering the report yields no visible action. No error message. Removing/commenting the code and the report is generated as expected.

I verified that the text45 control is variable. I get the same result whether the value is zero or non-zero.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

SC

Comment: A report without data should not show, even without code. Maybe just need to set subreport container CanGrow and CanShrink properties to yes. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

In my version of Access365, I get the subreport header and the subreport column headings, but no data (when there is no data). Cangrow and CanShrink have been set to yes since created for each subreport. When there is data, the subreport expands to accommodate all relevant records.

I need the entire subreport to not be visible if there is no data in the subreport.

Comment: Then code must go in Format event of section that holds the subreport. Event triggers for PrintPreview or direct to printer, not ReportView. Will probably still leave some white space where subreport sits. Trying setting container with 0 height in design.

Comment: Pretty close to what was going on. After (way too much) troubleshooting, I found that running the report to "Report View" was showing the empty table as described. Going to "Print Preview" and the table is no longer visible. Switching back to "Report View" and the report is not visible.
So, going directly to "Report View" erroneously shows the empty table. Resolution is to go to "Print Preview" instead.
I'm not sure why that "functionality" exists, but it was an annoying lesson to learn.